# Is there any way to make a nonlethal railgun?

Tags: military, railguns

Riot police are marching across the burning fields of the UN capital on Mars to quell pro alien insurrectionists. Ethics and activism dictate that no lethal weapons can be used on other humans. But since handheld railgun tech is already widespread for anti-alien use some generals in the chain of command want to save money. Here is their paraphrased conversation:

Steve: Bob, we need to get rid of these rebels, but we can’t use our big supply of lethal railguns. How can our police quell the riots *without* using the money we have set aside for personal use?

Bob: If only all those railguns we have could be nonlethal!

The railguns are similar to assault rifles, but they can get up to 2kps and rapid fire. Is there any way to make a railgun nonlethal without spending too much of the generals' vacation money?

Comment: There is no such thing as a non-lethal weapon; there are only *less lethal* weapons. (Because a truely non-lethal weapon is obviously a non-weapon.) To reduce the lethality of rail guns do what we do with firearms: fire less lethal projectiles. Ground salt, rubber etc. In other words, you make a less lethal rail gun in the same way that you make a less lethal sling, or less lethal bow, or less lethal shotgun, and so on.

Comment: Rubber bullets hurt a lot of people because the shooters use them improperly. Rubber bullets are usually made to be shot so they bounce off the ground before hitting the rioters.

Comment: R u familiar with Right Hand Rule? Basically the power of the accelerating projectile depends on how much juice(electricity) and mass of bullet, go with rubber bullet or chalk and go easy on the juice your target should be fine ;D

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? I think you're missing a big part of your question. Rebels + nonlethal rail gun = what exactly? Do you want to cripple all protesters? If you can disable, you can kill. It sounds like your entire plan is to randomly shoot into a crowd and then magic happens, the thread is stopped but nobody died. If that's your level of realism, you might as well say the rail gun is just non lethal. Could you please explain the strategy of your police force? Instead of a nonlethal weapon, choose a strategy that minimizes fatalities

Comment: What often happens in reality: use the other end of the gun. Beating protestors with the butt of a rifle is a traditional police violence technique.

Comment: Don't forget railguns (as we have them) require the bullet be made of *metal* you can put a rubber tip on it, but that might melt off as the metal heats during firing!

Comment: @user6916458 You could put the bullet into a plastic container (like a shotgun shell) with conducting wires. The entire bullet doesn't need to be made of metal.

Comment: The scenario is highly unlikely. This is a local law enforcement issue. If the government has seen fit to issue officers with a standard issue 'lethal' force option then by default they will have issued them with less lethal options. There isn't a police force in the developed world where the only use of force option - apart from going hands on is a firearm! Batons, handcuffs, tasers, OC spray, water cannons, baton rounds - the list goes on. And ALL of these options have somehow magically disappeared overnight. Not to mention new ones being invented in a supposedly high tech future.

Comment: @NomadMaker you could, but you run the rick of either the wires melting, or the surrounding plastic melting/catching fire.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's a railgun where the round is accelerated by the gun itself down the barrel by electronics...It's not like a gunpowder cartridge where the power level is determined by the powder charge in the round so you're trapped at whatever power level the round is.

So just dial down the acceleration in the barrel and at some point it would just be like lobbing bullets at people with your hands. Nothing says a railgun has to shoot at hypersonic speeds.

Then you would also need to to modify the bullet materials so they aren't so hard. Since there are no explosions and the acceleration is more gradual than a bullet you could conceivably use other materials designed to reduce the impact (putty or something maybe?).

The metallic part of the round would have to be minimized such that it is foil or powder and sheds so it can be slowed down by air resistance. Or impregnated through a softer medium.

That's about as nonlethal as you could manage with something like that where your impact surface is small making it difficult to distribute the force out and reduce the pressure exerted on impact. The smaller diameter your regular railgun rounds are, the more challenging this will be. Larger round diameters and round lengths let you do things like fire long sticks of putty that have much more mass but can also deform.

Comment: Pretty much this. You also can use coilguns with rubber-coated rods instead - even modern RL portable coilguns constructed by some guy in a garage have a considerable punch (enough to go through an unopened soda can), but probably aren't lethal, especially if the projectile will have blunt end. The only think to keep in mind tho is that the effective firing distance will suffer from the projectile speed greatly. But I think that for a riot control even 100-meter fire range would be bit excessive anyway.

Comment: This is technically correct if we just look at the title of the question, but it will not stop any protesters. As we all know from stonings, you can kill people by throwing stuff at them. The standard in this stack exchange is really low if you're collecting upvotes here. Could you include how this will still be a weapon to control, I quote, riots? Even medieval armor was able to completely deflect arrows that would fly through a normal human body like hot butter. This sounds really ineffective once the protesters figure out the concept of protecting themselves

Comment: @Raditz_35 well, you could combine the railgun with a video feed and some AI to always deliver EXACTLY the punch required to hurt someone through whatever armor the have (or not) and not kill them. Here, railguns would work perfectly. You could take one shot at someone unprepared and knock them out (or give em a light bruise, whatever desired), and then just take a shot at the guy next to him, clad in full sci-fi armor, and without any adjustment by the shooter, give him the same amount of pain . Brilliant imho

Comment: @DarthBiomech ‘Are not _likely_ to be lethal’ is a much better way to sy this.  Airsoft guns can kill people and have far less energy (and similarly blunt projectiles) than a backyard coil-gun. At minimum, it’s possible for it to nick a critical artery or vein and cause the victim to bleed out before emergency medical services can get there.

Comment: @Raditz_35 I feel like this is moving goalposts a bit as you seem to expect be all end all 100% non-lethal weapon that is also automatically effective against everything from puppies to armoured knights. The stoning and plate armour and stoning examples I feel are specially misleading in real world circumstances. Protestors throw rocks during riots. Do you consider that lethal force because stonings can kill people? And plate armour also works against rubber bullets but how many rioters do you see running around with plate armour?

Comment: @Raditz_35 You can certainly argue a frame challenge though but that is broader than just about how to adapt a tool to be more fit for purpose.

Comment: Honestly this is the answer, Railguns get shown in fiction as hypersonic but in reality, the challenge is actually to match the performance of conventional guns. A non-lethal shot from a railgun is far easier technologically, you just dial down the electrical input to the gun for that shot. Maybe swap it out for a rubber-coated shot..

Comment: All the people commenting about my comment seem to agree that it's more to it than just lowering the force but all about strategy, circumstances and adaptability of the protesters, even though they word it as if there was some disagreement. I think this answer needs adjustment. My example is not misleading, a longbow generates way more force than throw. It's super easy to shield yourself from slow, nonlethal bullets. Teargas and water throwers, I mean, the clue is in reality. Police could shoot and very rarely do use rubber bullets, but they typically don't. It's ineffective and dangerous

Comment: @Raditz_35 I'll have to just repeat that you seem to expect the railgun to be the be-all-end all riot suppression tool. That's not the way I interpreted the question, but if that's what you believe what the OP intended then you should frame challenge. Because just like you said, police don't just use rubber bullets, or just use water cannon, or just use tear gas. There are multiple tools.

Comment: Rail gun projectiles -- by the laws of physics -- must be metallic, which means they're lethal in the wrong circumstances.

Comment: @RonJohn That statement also applies to rubber bullets necessarily utilizing explosions, and even batons. Everything is lethal in the wrong circumstances. There are a number of ways to deal with the metallic part of the round. It can be be minimized like being foil or powdered and made to shed so air resistance can deal with it, or distributed as a powder throughout whatever the impact medium is. Nothing says it has to be a metal slug but these would require considerably better railgun tech to drive down the barrel.

Comment: @RonJohn Of course, if you're cheap like the generals in the OP's question might be, special purpose ammo might be out of the question so dialing back on the railguns would just result in lobbing hunks of metal really hard. Definitely not ideal but still less lethal than hypersonic rounds.

Comment: @DKNguyen the whole question -- like many on WB -- is divorced from reality.

Comment: @RonJohn Yes, I agree. The question does a lot of gaps. For example, the cheap generals might not care about actual non-lethality, and just want to circumvent the dictates of ethics and activism mentioned. In which case, how lethal it might still be under some conditions would be rather irrelevant. What would be relevant would be the the reduced lethality and appearances that an effort was made to reduce lethality.

Comment: The problem with using a non-solid is that instead of propelling it out of the barrel of the gun, you are more likely just spreading it around the interior of the barrel. You would need something to contain the material until it leaves the barrel, like a sabot. After that, you could use even ferrofluid as a projectile, although that might have other problems, like running into people's eyes. Which also brings up another point, getting hit in the eye with a projectile can still cause blindness, so it can still cause major injuries, even if it's plain water going at 150mph.

Comment: @computercarguy The eye thing is true but is also true of pretty much every other implement in existence as well. Eyes were just not meant to come into contact with other objects.

Answer (score 9):

**Shock-Bayonets**

A railgun needs to have a big powersource in form of a battery to work. We could use this electric energy to power a bayonet-like device, which the police could use as a shocking stick, kinda like an electric cattle prod.

[image]

Comment: For comparison, tasers or shock prods typically run on a handful of consumer-grade batteries, so using a railgun-sized power source is major overkill and is not needed in the slightest. This solution seems rather unrelated to the railgun itself - you could bolt a taser onto virtually *any* weapon and call it "nonlethal".

Comment: @NuclearHoagie well there is a difference between adding an independent taser system and utilizing the already available battery pack of the railgun. It would at least save some weight. Remember that the great power supply is still used for the railgun itself. The taser is just a free bonus.

Comment: I wonder whether it would be possible to statically charge up a round prior to firing so that it shocks the target on impact, and then shoot such a round at lower velocities.

Answer (score 7):

Fit them as [rifle grenade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rifle_grenade) launchers. When the railgun projectile gets to the end of the barrel, the fast-moving but lightweight projectile hits a much heavier grenade, sending it off at a sedate pace that-a-way. Inside the grenades, you have traditional less-lethal payloads: tear gas, flashbangs, etc. Disadvantages are indifferent range and accuracy, not huge drawbacks under the circumstances.

The size and shape of the railgun itself (fairly lightweight, long durable barrel) would make it ideal for close quarters combat, which may or may not be lethal depending on how much practice your troops have had with it.

Comment: "hits a much heavier grenade, sending it off at a sedate pace" - at 2 km/s... I don't think so. The grenade would disintegrate right then and there.

Comment: @Alexander 2 km/s is only about twice as fast as a conventional assault rifle round. Depending on the size of your projectile, it wouldn't be that far out of the ballpark of what's been done before.

Comment: "what's been done before" - can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Alexander Existing "bullet-trap" style rifle grenades, that is. The railgun projectile would be in the same ballpark of kinetic energy (perhaps a few times as much, but potentially much closer if it was lighter than an equivalent rifle round) so the engineering requirements would be similar.

Comment: The only type of "bullet-trap" style rifle grenades suitable for railguns would be "rod type" (because railguns have no muzzle blast), and this type was relatively poor performing 100 years ago. With 2 km/s speeds, there is a good chance of a grenade and the railgun itself coming apart during firing.

Comment: @Alexander  where did you dig up your 2km/s from? It's a railgun. Aka you can tweak the speed of the projectile almost without any restrictions. And you wouldn't fire at maximum power for riot control obviously.

Comment: @Alexander and yes, with GUNPOWDER (or nitrose pulver), those were performing badly. Because you have a fucking explosion meeting too much resistance. But railguns accelerate gradually. Meaning that "rod type" grenades could work perfectly. (Of course depending on the specifics of the railgun, but there's a good chance they are designed this way). And they absolutely would be, given that they were designed against aliens, so potentially doubling as grenade launchers would concievably have been a "nice to have" in the design specs

Comment: Nitpick: ‘long barrel’ is at odds with ‘ideal for close quarters combat’. If the overall length of a weapon is too long, it cannot be used effectively in close quarters, period.

Comment: @Hobbamok "2kps" is for the OP's question. Yes, railguns potentially be depowered, and that can be the solution. My concern with the original speed is that at 2 km/s the collision is too powerful, producing small shards and even liquefying the metal, and it's all happening inside the railgun's barrel.

Comment: @Alexander why did you start your quote directly AFTER the relevant word??? "up to 2kps" is what OP said. And the question is only about COST EFFECTIVE changes, meaning that a small software Update is absolutely within range, if thats even necessary.  Again: barrel grenades might already be in the specs for fighting aliens, so all we need are rubber tipped ones

Answer (score 6):

Much depends on how the railgun technology works.

For example, would it be possible to replace the bullets with very small metal pellets (possibly metal foam or wireballs) covered in soft rubber and ablative foam? This would enormously decrease the range, but the weapons could become nonlethal - less metal to be electromagnetically accelerated, *way* less kinetic energy, no penetrative power to speak of.

Or the other way round: **heavier** projectiles, that would not be accelerated to the same disastrous speeds, and whose nature could be further rendered less lethal. Imagine a rigid steel wire, powering a nerf bullet with a soft (or not so soft) rubber tip. This could still have a significant range - it would be a sort of arrow - while not being necessarily lethal. The energy transfer from the railgun coil would probably shorten the railgun lifetime significantly - instead of a quick electromagnetic fling you'd get a comparatively slower build-up.

Or "micro-flechette rounds" - depending on the size of the flechettes, air friction could slow them down enough to not be (immediately) lethal, or not unless some vital organ gets mulched (e.g. liver or spleen). The railgun would still be lethal at point-blank range, which could be useful in some scenarios. And of course it would depend on which bullets were fired.

This might have any negative effect on the railguns' life that we might desire (from none at all, to turning them into one-shot blunderbusses when the internal linear coupled coil overloads and cracks, or even melts down).

Also the firing could have lots of attached special effects, like the ablative foam exploding with a loud bang (2 kps is way over the speed of sound), or the wireballs igniting due to atmospheric friction (that is actually very unlikely at sea level, but who knows... maybe magnesium-steel wireballs were selling for a song and someone thought they might cheaply replace pure steel ones).

"Nonlethal" means actually "not intentionally and directly lethal". Someone hit in the face, or at point-blank range, or set on fire by an unintentionally incendiary round could still die. A hard hit in the wrong place can still kill someone with [the appropriate condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_QT_syndrome). Hitting someone who is driving... etc.

Comment: How about some kind of chaff bullet, whose muzzle velocity breaks it up into a cloud of tiny pieces of foil? They slow down dramatically, but a cloud of them would sting like heck.

Answer (score 2):

Gas Parachutes.

The bullets are long and include a fluid chamber. Further they have an air duct leading from the front of the bullet to a parachute-like part of the bullet. As long as the bullet is faster than x, the parachute-like part expands outwards slowing the bullet down greatly. Below speed x it doesn't expand anymore so the bullet won't instantly fall to the ground.

The bullets have a foam tip so they don't hurt.

The foam is connected to the chamber - but only when or after the parachute expands. This way you can put in a non lethal contact poison which doesn't hurt people handling the bullets.

Answer (score 1):

A big problem with these "less lethal" guns is the projectile speed and muzzle energy are set by the explosive charge, which means they're always the same. But the large projectile slows down quickly as it flies due to air drag, so it will be "less lethal" over a short range of distance, useless at long range, and at close range it will crack skulls. If it was weak enough to be safe at close range, it would then be useless at 20 meters...

[image]

Sure, the military want railguns because they can shoot projectiles much faster than powder, but being electric, railguns and coilguns have another feature: adjustable projectile speed.

So you could make a "less lethal" railgun by having a scope rangefinder that automatically
measures distance to target and adjusts shot power to deliver the required projectile speed at the target.

This could lead to some interesting plot twists, for example:

- The integrated face and shape recognition software which was originally designed to avoid shooting people in the face doesn't work that well with aliens, leading to various losses of appendages, and of course accusations of "racist guns designer to murder only aliens".
- Likewise, power should be adjusted depending on the target ; after all some aliens come with thick scales and would shrug off bullets and others are quite squishy and would explode if they receive a shot intended for the former. Great opportunity for unintended misbehavior of software "features" and class action lawsuits.
- If you aim at someone far away, the gun will set itself to high power, then if someone steps in front of it at the shot is fired, they get obliterated.

Although... I'd recommend a coilgun instead. Railguns require a conductive sabot to propel the round, and that will fly off and split into several pieces, possibly sharp and very hot, turning the thing into a kind of shotgun. But everyone knows the real reason it was decommissioned was cost ; after all those sabots (and lawsuits) are expensive, and if you use a coilgun you can shoot the same projectile several times if you recover it...

Answer (score 0):

This answer considers the case where a railgun works under the same principle as current technology.

Step 1: Calculate the % of the default current needed to make the railgun bullets as slow as they need to be to be considered non-lethal. Eg: 10% of the original power makes bruises but doesn't penetrate people.

Step 2: Add a resistor (obviously low resistance, high power) in parallel to the rail-bullet-rail circuit in order to suck out the remaining percentage of the current. Resistors, and their accompanying metal connector modules, will probably be dirt cheap.

Comment: Bullets are devastating because of the kinetic energy that they deliver to a target. They tend to have low mass and high velocity. What you want for a "less-lethal" weapon though is not so much kinetic energy, but a big wallop of _momentum._ If you simply dial down the velocity, then the tiny bullet that was ideal for the "lethal" application will carry nowhere near enough momentum for the "less-lethal" application. You need a big, massive projectile for that.

Comment: I think you're jumping from one end of the other; surely between "lethal" and "useless" there will be some sweet point. I agree with enlarging the projectile - kind of "flying fists".

Answer (score 0):

Ferro-fluid adhesive gel balls. The ferro-fluid provides the ferrous material necessary to accelerate the ball electromagnetically. Then the ferro-fluid causes the ball material to wrap around the target immobilizing them. Maybe a binary composition that mixes on contact and causes the ferrous particles to simultaneous repel and attract each other causing them to spread out evenly around the target. Then quickly hardening to impede movement. Removal could be done with a ceramic knife to part the gel and peel it off of the target. Or an antagonist component that breaks down the gel.

Answer (score 0):

Bolo projectiles. When launched from the rail gun the weights separate drawing a thin cable between them. The cable hits the targets and the weights cause the cable to wrap around the target and then lock somehow when they finish wrapping. Of course, as with any seemingly non-lethal weapon, accidents will happen (wrapping around the throat, crushing the skull, etc.) but they are rare incidents.

Comment: Or just headshotting someone with the bola-ball. Which, in a riot situation, is gonna be pretty common.

Comment: @Erik, yeah, but this is just a best attempt to utilize existing hardware without too much expense. You gotta expect a 'few' accidents. I envision this as being preferred with individuals fleeing from the authorities. Rather than shooting them dead, you shoot a bolo round at their legs, then catch up with them at a more leisurely pace. In any event, you use the tools you have been allocated.